# Deploying prediction model on heroku

Tags: python, github, flask, heroku, deployment

I'm trying to deploy my prediction model on Heroku via Github. once my model is deployed it doesn't open up and shows the below error:
   Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command

Answer (score 0):

You can check the logs on Heroku to see if there are any problems. You can get there by following the below steps:

1. Go to your dashboard in Heroku website.
2. Select your app that you are trying to deploy.
3. On the top right you can see option called "More". Click it.
4. You will get a drop-down of options. Select view logs.
5. You can see the logs and try to understand if any imports are missing or any other problem persists.